# Which PHP version do I have?

Tags: php

my hosting site says I have selected php version 7.4

[image]

but when I check with the terminal I get

[image]

What version do I really have?? I need to have php 5.3 or above!! If I run some warmup command I get following error:

[image]

Comment: I would say you have PHP7.4 being used in the web server and PHP4.4.9 in the PHP CLI. They dont have to be the same and often are not on hosted servers.

Comment: Ask your host where they keep later versions of the CLI, Or this [may help you find a newer version](https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-switch-between-multiple-php-versions-in-ubuntu/) for the CLI

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I checked with my hosting provider, they have no idea about the CLI... they are kept telling me that I have 7.4 php.... 

As you can see, if I keep 4.4 as my CLI version, I can not use my application... is there any way I can change CLI version by myself?? (Yes I checked an article you gave a link for, it is still talking about a PHP version!!)

Comment: Your hosting company might not divulge that information, due to security reasons and might have brushed you off politely.

Comment: If this is shared hosting, you wont be able to install another version of PHP. That can only be done by the Hosters